# the program stops working whenver div command is executed

Tags: assembly, masm32

```
lea   ecx,wtavg
push  ecx
call  StdOut
xor   eax,eax
lea   eax,wtsum     ; I have values stored in these variables(integer data)
mov   eax,[eax]
lea   ecx,sumwts
mov   ecx,[ecx]
div   ebx           ; The problem lies here, "Windows Stopped working" 
lea   edi,temp1
mov   [edi],ebx
lea   edi,rem
mov   [edi],edx
print ustr$(eax),0,0
lea   eax,pt
push  eax
call  StdOut
lea   eax,rem
mov   eax,[eax]
mov   edx,100
mul   edx
lea   ebx,temp1
mov   ebx,[ebx]
div   ebx
xchg  ebx,eax
print ustr$(ebx),13,10
lea   eax, prompt
push  eax
call  StdOut
mov   eax,100
push  eax
lea   eax,temp1
push  eax
call  StdIn
call  ExitProcess
```

Comment: Perhaps a bit more detail on what results you expect and what exact error you are seeing.

Comment: Ensure: `0 <= edx < ebx`

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anywhere where you've actually *set* `ebx` to something before attempting to divide by it.

It's unlikely to end well if `ebx` is set to zero at that point since [Documentation for the `div` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html) indicates that an exception is raised for that situation:

```
if (Source == 0) Exception (DE); // divide error
```

If you're trying to divide something by `sumwts`, you should probably load that into `ebx` or use `ecx` as part of the `div` instruction:

```
lea  ecx,sumwts
mov  ebx,[ecx]        ; Or leave as mov ecx,[ecx]
div  ebx              ;   then use div ecx.
```

You may also want to ensure that `edx` has been set to zero somewhere before the `div`, since that's used in the division as well. For `div ebx`, the actions are effectively:

```
tmp <- edx:eax
eax <- tmp / ebx, exception if eax would overflow
edx <- tmp % ebx
```